# How can I set a label form database

Tags: asp.net

I want to set a label with something out a database.
This is my query:

```
 string strQuery = "Select * FROM Contacts Where User='" + strSelectedUser + "'";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, Global.myConn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                da.Fill(Global.ds, "Tabel");
```

Now I want to set a label

```
lblContact.Text=......[column database = name]....?
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use blow code to set label value from database.

First check that your query is retuning value then assign the value to label text

```
if(Global.ds.Tables["Tabel"].Row.Count>0)
{

lblContact.Text=Global.ds.Tables["Tabel"].Rows[0]["Colomn_Name"].toString();
}
```